# Перенос домена с одного хостинга на другой

Tags: домен

Здравствуйте, такой вопросик как переносить доменное имя, например с friendhosting на bitte-hosting.com ?

Comment: [Трансфер доменного имени][1].


  [1]: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет прямого отношения к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для домена переписываются или же NS-сервера, или же IP-адрес и это всё.